# Sharing image through FBDialog fails in facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook

I am attempting to share a generated image through the facebook app with the FBDialog class. The idea is to allow tagging of friends and locations so the SLComposeViewController isn't quite as ideal (though I am falling back to that). The problem is that after it opens the facebook app and the users presses share, it never actually shares. It gets stuck at the loading screen and the bar keeps starting back from 0%, going past 100%, then back to 0.

I'm using the following code. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my implementation or with the facebook app itself.

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos]) {
    FBPhotoParams *params = [[FBPhotoParams alloc] init];
    UIImage *img = [self generatePrayerImage];
    params.photos = @[img];
    
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:params
                                     clientState:nil
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call,
                                                   NSDictionary *results,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                                                       error.description);
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                             }
                                         }];
}
```

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by setting the correct facebook app name in my info.plist. For some reason there must have been a small difference between the one I set on developer.facebook.com and my app.